# Multiple message sends in Akka-Scala-Camel-TCP Sockets going to dead letters

Tags: scala, tcp, apache-camel, akka

When I get one message from a non akka client through TCP socket, I need to reply as three messages. In the following sample given below, only the first one goes through properly to the sender (the TCP client which is non AKKA). The rest of the two goes to dead letter. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

```
object TcpExample {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val system = ActorSystem("some-system")
    val tcpConsumer = system.actorOf(Props[TcpConsumer])
    }
class TcpConsumer extends Consumer {
    def endpointUri = "mina2:tcp://localhost:6200?textline=true"
    def receive = {
        case msg: CamelMessage => {
            sender ! msg.bodyAs[String]
            sender ! msg.bodyAs[String]     // This goes to dead letter
            sender ! msg.bodyAs[String]     // This goes to dead letter
        }
        case msg: Failure => sender ! msg
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about the internals of the akka/camel integration, let me try and demonstrate what's happening here.  First, as I mentioned in my comment, the `sender` in your actor does not directly refer to the TCP client that is on the other side of the system.  It's lower level than that; it's whatever `ActorRef` sent your `Consumer` the `CamelMessage` in the first place.  So what actor is that?  Let me try and explain what I think is happening.

1. When you set up tcp based a camel consumer, based on the `endpointUri` there will be a piece of code (from Camel) that is going to bind to the host and port from the `endpointUri`.
2. When a new connection request comes in (based on an external client opening a connection to that socket), some sort of actor is probably spun up to handle that individual connection.  So there will be 1-n "connection handler" actor instances matching the number of open connections.
3. When a message comes inbound, it more than likely goes through that connection handler actor.  From there, it is either being sent to your consumer via `ask (?)`, or another short lived actor is being spun up to handle that individual message.
4. Either way, next stop is your consumer, where it's `receive` function gets hit with a `CamelMessage` representing the payload from the message sent from the remove client.  When this happens, the actors `sender` is still whatever sent the message in step 3.
5. Your consumer will now send a message back to the `sender` and then from there it will eventually be routed back to the connection handler for that connection.  In there, it will write back to the socket, in a conversational state.  One message in, one message out.

I think your problem is that you are breaking the "one in, one out" paradigm here.  When you get your `CamelMessage`, you are only supposed to respond to that message once, which will evantually trickle back up to the TCP client on the other end of the socket.  I don't think the framework expects another response, and that's why you see deadletters for the other two responses.

So this begs the question, what scenario do you have that requires a "1 in, 3 out" paradigm vs the expected "1 in, one out" one that the framework seems to expect?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. But even after making this change, the wrong behaviour remains the same.

Comment: My guess is that the `sender()` in this case is a short lived actor used for a `Future`. It can only be responded to once before it stops itself (after completing the `Promise` tied to the `Future`). Thats why the second two always lead to dead letters.

Comment: Here the sender() is NOT an actor based client. It is just a TCP client. The whole idea is to build a server component that still supports the existing clients and applications. So is there any way to accomplish the same? Thanks

Comment: I think you are confusing the sender of the original tcp message (the tcp client code on the other side of the system) and the sender of the `CamelMessage` to your `Consumer` component.  In the `Consumer` actor, I believe the `sender` is going to be an `Actor` that is listening to that endpoint uri (as part of the akka/camel integration) and then sends a message (a `CamelMessage`) to your `Consumer`, expecting you to reply after which it will write back to the open tcp socket and the client on the other end will receive that message contents

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments and suggestions. Looks like I may have to change the strategy to achieve the business requirements. Thanks once again.